# Why are permalinks not working on LAMP install?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, lamp, permalinks

I just upgraded to the latest Ubuntu release on a VPS. When it finished the permalinks no longer worked.

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

My virtual host file looks like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.nameofsite.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nameofsite.org
    Redirect permanent / http://www.nameofsite.org/
 </VirtualHost>
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really annoying, but there was an AllowOverride None in the apache2.conf file. Should the sites-enabled files outrank the apache2.conf file? I had explicit AllowOverride All in the  nameofsite.org.conf file!!